# Como Enumarar filas en DataGridView en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una duda de como poder enumarar las filas en un datagridView en c#, hice esto pero quiero que se muestre automaticamente sin tener que agregar una columna

```
private void dataGridViewCatalogoPartesTotal_CellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == Columna.Index)
        {
            e.Value = e.RowIndex + 1;
        }
    }
```

Y este fue el resultado

[image: imagen1]

Pero yo quiero enumerarlo de esta forma

[image: imagen2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

para mostrar el número de fila en el encabezado de la fila, podríamos usar el evento RowPostPaint del control DataGridView.

Y luego se aplica lo que ya tienes, pero esta vez en vez de dibujarlo en una colunma nueva lo genera en la que trae por defecto el datagrid

```
this.dgvUserDetails.RowPostPaint += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventHandler(this.dgvUserDetails_RowPostPaint);

    private void dgvUserDetails_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
    {
            using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(dgvUserDetails.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor))
            {
                  e.Graphics.DrawString((e.RowIndex + 1).ToString(), e.InheritedRowStyle.Font, b, e.RowBounds.Location.X + 10, e.RowBounds.Location.Y + 4);
            }
    }
```

Comment: una consulta, la primera instrucción
this.dgvUserDetails.RowPostPaint += new System.Windows.................
que función tiene? por que seguí tus instrucciones indicadas, pero no utilice esta instrucción mencionada y mi proyecto funciona a la perfección la enumeración de tres DataGridView que estoy utilizando sin utilizar la instrucción mencionada.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

En el evento `RowEnter` coloca este fragmento del código.

```c#
private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.Value = (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString();
}
```

Saludos.